# Is SecurityContextHolder necessary

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, jwt

I have implemented a specific Oauth token. It is created when the client infos satisfy the specific condition. When i analyzed the code that is written before for jwt used id and password.  The contextSecurityHolder and authentication mechanism are almost same in every code. What is the main purpose of the usage of those and is contextSecurityHolder always necessary?

Here is an example code:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String token = null;


        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.contains("Bearer")) {
            token = authHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = tokenManager.getUsernameToken(token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (username != null && token != null
                && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            if (tokenManager.tokenValidate(token)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upassToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, new ArrayList<>());
                upassToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upassToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecurityContextHolder` holds the authentication information in a `ThreadLocal` context (by default). It is a fundamental helper class to Spring Security, which provides access to the security context. You (and the framework) can access to the authentication in every methods run in the same thread. It is necessery even if you protect urls or use method security, but sometimes you need user information in business logic too and you can get it from there.
So the answer is yes, it is always needed, if you use spring security.

Comment: Are there any token for just store the id of the client. The code above has UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and for setting the SecurityContextHolder i need a class that implements the Authentication interface isn't it? @zlaval

Comment: You can find the spring implementations here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationToken.html Also, it is easy to create own implementation extending from the linked class.